# Чему равно выражение после преобразования к числу оператором "+" в JS?

Tags: javascript

По задумке метод sum() должен поочередно складывать значения ключей объекта, которые являются числами, вместо этого он складывает их все включая методы. Подскажите в чем моя ошибка.

```js
let calculator = {
  //Сохраняет два значения как свойства объекта
  read() {
    let prop1 = prompt();
    let prop2 = prompt();

    this[`${prop1}`] = prop1;
    this[`${prop2}`] = prop2;
  },
  //Ввозвращает сумму значений свойств объекта
  sum() {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let key in this) {
      //+calculator.read == NaN, +calculator.sum == NaN
      alert(+this[key]);

      if ((+this[key]) != NaN) {
        sum += this[key];
      }
    }

    return sum;
  }

};

calculator.read();

alert(calculator.sum());
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы перебираете this

```
for (let key in this) {
```

this в вашем коде это обьект calculator в котром у вас находятся методы read, sum а так же эти значения:

```
this[`${prop1}`] = prop1;
this[`${prop2}`] = prop2;
```

Я бы создал отдельный обьект в обьекте calculator для хранения значений. Например так:

```
let calculator = {
  values: {},
  read() {
    this.values[`${Date.now()}`] = +prompt();
    this.values[`${Date.now()}`] = +prompt();
  },
  sum() {
    return Object.values(this.values).reduce((summ, value) => summ + value);
  }
};

calculator.read();

alert(calculator.sum());
```